# Setup windows 2012 AD in Hyper-V for a Test environment

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Im trying to setup a Windos 2012 R2 test environment on my work computer (a laptop).
I have a AD, DHCP and DNS server on **server A**, and a **client** connecting to the doman and that works. The client can ping the AD server and gets a valid IP adress.

If I ping google.com from the **client** I get the IP adress but I dont get any responses (request time out). If i ping google.com from **server A** it works as it should.

**Server A** have a connection to the Internet through a "external network switch" in hyper-v, which gets its internet from a router and the **client** is connected to a "internal network switch". May the poblem be that **server A** is behind a router?

Can I make this solution to work regadless the network my laptop is connected to?
At home i have one IP adress, at work its a totally different range.

What I would like is to use my laptops internet connection, regardless wifi or wired, to act as incomming internet, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Internal switch means that your client can communicate with your parent partition in Hyper-V (your host machine) and other virtual machines. It resolve google.com to IP address, because uses your ServerA DNS server, which has access to the internet and can provide you right IP address, but your client can not communicate this IP address because it has no router. 
 You need to install on ServerA the NAT service and set server's IP address as default gateway in the client to get it connected both internal and external networks.